# Text Expander broken upon Snow Leopard Upgrade

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, compatibility, textexpander

I've been using [Text Expander](http://www.smileonmymac.com/TextExpander/) for years.

However, I found out today it doesn't work on my newly upgraded (to Snow Leopard) Macbook Pro anymore. I know that there are a lot of applications that are not compatible with Snow Leopard, and developers around the world are working on them to work again on our beautiful macs.

My questions are:
1. Is TextExpander supposed to NOT work on Snow Leopard?
2. What is a good substitution to replace TextExpander? or any updates from TextExpander developers?

Answer (score 2):

TextExpander 2.7 is Snow Leopard compatible. You can download it at http://www.smileonmymac.com/TextExpander/download.html.

If you are having issues with the latest version on Snow Leopard, please contact support@smileonmymac.com and we will sort it out. - Jean MacDonald/SmileOnMyMac.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that TextExpander just needs a little push in the right direction.

1. Go into SYSTEM PREFERENCES and click on TextExpander
2. Click on the 2nd Tab should be Preferences or Settings
3. uncheck "active TextExpander"
4. wait a couple of seconds or even better exit the SYSTEM PREFERENCES
5. open them again and this time check the "activate TextExpander" box.

By now TextExpander should show up in your MenuBar as usual. At least this
did the trick for me. Hope it's the same with yours.

PS: I'm on the german version here, sorry for not being able to give a more
precise description of the buttons and co.

### EDIT:

After writing this and checking my preferences TextExpander was gone again and
not to be found in my menubar :(

After uncheck and check the activate button a couple of times it finally showed
up again.